# How to refresh content of iframe from controller in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I have a question about combination of asp.net mvc and iframe.

I'm trying to edit retrieved data from db on iframe.
The problem is that when the page firstly loads the parent contents, iframe contents is also loaded and can't be edited later.

```
public ActionResult StudentDetail(string id)
  {
      Student student_data = null;
      if (id != null)
      {
          student_data = getId(id);
      }
      else
      {
          return null;
      }
      return PartialView("StudentDetail",student_data);
  }
```

As you can see above code,if any ID is selected by hyperlink of view,
it returns partial view for iframe.When it comes to this page at the first time,
becuase any Id isn't selected,it returns null.
Below code is snippet of the parent view.This calls controller and content is set by null when it comes to loading this page at the first time.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe id="myFlame" class="embed-responsive-item" src="/Home/StudentDetail" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="false" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

After loading the parent page and iframe page, user push the hyperlink to pop up the iframe to edit data.The snippet of code is below,it calls javascript to send id to controller

```
 <td><a href="javascript:(0);"  class="anchorDetail" data-id="@student.id" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">@student.id</a></td>
```

Code of javascript is below.

```
<script>
        var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Home/StudentDetail';
        $(function () {
            $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {


                var $buttonClicked = $(this);
                var id = $buttonClicked.attr('data-id');
                var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: { "Id": id },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        $('#myFlame').html(data);
                        $('#myModal').modal(options);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Dynamic content load failed.");
                    }
                });
            });
            //$("#closebtn").on('click',function(){
            //    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

            $("#closbtn").click(function () {
                debugger;
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

After pushing a hyperlink,javascript send the data to controller and retrieve data from db and return partialView of StudentDetail.cshtml.but it still shows empty iframe.

How can I refresh the content of iframe?

Comment: `$('#myFlame').html(data);` I don't believe you can change an iFrame's content like this, although maybe someone knows better. Perhaps you'd be better with a regular div if that's what you want to do. An iframe is more like a separate browser with your window. It points to another URL, as you know. So you can tell it to reload the content from that URL, or change to another URL and load from there - just like you can with a regular browser window. Note that you have to do that from JavaScript, since it's all about manipulating what's happening in the browser, not on the server.